# Python writing multiple arrays as csv

Tags: python, csv

I have an opencv python program that runs correctly and prints the values.  However when I try to write the printed values to a csv file, I am getting errors.
The following is the code:

```
for testingPath in paths.list_images(args["testing"]):
    # load the image and make predictions
    image = cv2.imread(testingPath)
    boxes = detector(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    # loop over the bounding boxes and draw them
    for b in boxes:
        (x, y, w, h) = (b.left(), b.top(), b.right(), b.bottom())
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (w, h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        #print(basename(testingPath),"CX:"+str(x),"CY:"+str(y),"Width:"+str(w),"Height:"+str(h),brandname,"Number of brands detected: {}".format(len(boxes))) -----this prints all the required values without problem on the console
```

I tried doing this:

I added an argument before the for loop starts:

```
ap.add_argument("-i", "--index", required=True, help="Path to directory of output")
output = open(args["index"], "w")
```

and used the loop as follows:

```
for testingPath in paths.list_images(args["testing"]):
    # load the image and make predictions
    image = cv2.imread(testingPath)
    #filename = testingPath[testingPath.rfind("/") + 1:]
    boxes = detector(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    #print(basename(testingPath), brandname,"Number of brands detected: {}".format(len(boxes)))
    # loop over the bounding boxes and draw them
    for b in boxes:
        (x, y, w, h) = (b.left(), b.top(), b.right(), b.bottom())
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (w, h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        #print(basename(testingPath),"CX:"+str(x),"CY:"+str(y),"Width:"+str(w),"Height:"+str(h),brandname,"Number of brands detected: {}".format(len(boxes)))
        dat = str([x, y, w, h, brandname, len(boxes)])
        output.write("{},{}\n".format(testingPath, "".join(dat)))
```

The above code prints the values as follows:

```
/home/mycomp/VideoExtract/28157.jpg,[83, 349, 164, 383, 'Pirelli', 1]
```

I am trying to get rid of the [] brackets.  The desired action is to write the values that gets printed into a csv / text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing data in CSV format is a very common task - there is a [library called csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#module-csv) you could use.

Make your output variable a CSV writer

```
output = csv.writer(open(args["index"], "w"))
```

Replace your last two lines

```
dat = str([x, y, w, h, brandname, len(boxes)])
output.write("{},{}\n".format(testingPath, "".join(dat)))
```

with this line

```
output.writerow((testingPath, x, y, w, h, brandname, len(boxes)))
```

Comment: this sample code does not intend to make suggestions to improve code quality and/or readability.